# How to pass ATL com class object as paramater to COM

Tags: c++, com, atl

Like [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/698273/atl-i-want-to-create-a-coclass-that-i-can-use-as-a-parameter-for-a-method-in-my), but when I pass a string into the method, the string in com class is wrong, here is the code:

com server - Com.idl:

```
interface IParamClass : IUnknown
{
    [] HRESULT SetString([in] BSTR str);
}

interface IMyClass : IUnknown
{
    [] HRESULT PassComClassAsParam([in] IParamClass* parm);
}
```

ParamClass.cpp

```
class ATL_NO_VTABLE CParamClass : ...
{
...
public:
    BSTR m_str;

    STDMETHOD(SetString)(BSTR str);
};

STDMETHODIMP CParamClass::SetString(BSTR str)
{
    m_str = str;
    return S_OK;
}
```

MyClass.cpp:

```
STDMETHODIMP CMyClass::PassComClassAsParam( IParamClass* param)
{
    CParamClass *obj = (CParamClass*)param;
    BSTR str = obj->m_str;    //debugging here, is wrong string
...
}
```

C# Client:

```
MyClass myobj = new MyClass();
ParamClass param = new ParamClass();
param.SetString("Test String!");
myobj.PassComClassAsParam(param);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make a copy of string argument here since you are not controlling the lifetime of the value:

```
STDMETHODIMP CParamClass::SetString(BSTR str)
{
    m_str = str; // str is valid here, but you don't know when
                 // the value is destroyed later
    return S_OK;
}
```

By the time you use the value through `m_str` variable, the string is already freed and destroyed, hence you see it "wrong".

The typical solution is:

```
class ATL_NO_VTABLE CParamClass : ...
{
...
public:
    CComBSTR m_str; // <<--- Note CComBSTR

    STDMETHOD(SetString)(BSTR str);
};

STDMETHODIMP CParamClass::SetString(BSTR str)
{
    m_str = str;
    return S_OK;
}
```

Comment: This will only work if there's no marshalling, otherwise the `IParamClass*` pointer may point to a proxy and then the cast will be illegal.

Comment: @sharptooth are there any guide for lifetime of com object control?

Comment: @Roman Can you tell me why the previous BSTR m_str was released?

Comment: Why m_str releases previous string when it is assigned new value?

Comment: it seems I didn't assign any new value for m_str.

Comment: @Kamil In this case it's about a BSTR lifetime. BSTR is an "in" parameter so the caller must only keep the BSTR alive for the duration of the call. Onc the call has completed the caller is free to release the BSTR. So if the callee needs the BSTR after the call then it must copy it. In your early code you only has a raw pointer which would become dandling after the call. The new code suggested in this answer deep-copies the BSTR so the caller releasing its copy makes no difference to the callee.